# How to send requests to custom pocketbase routes, using the pocketbase javascript sdk?

Tags: javascript, pocketbase

I am trying to find a 'native' way to send post requests to my pocketbase server, from my svelte frontend :

**main.go:**

```
    app.OnBeforeServe().Add(func(e *core.ServeEvent) error {
        e.Router.AddRoute(echo.Route{
            Method: http.MethodPost,
            Path: "/api/myRoute",
            Handler: func(c echo.Context) error {
                // custom logic here: compute custom_value using parameters
                custom_value := "cool_value"
                return c.String(200, custom_value)
            },
        })
        return nil
    })
```

I would like to do something similar to the following :

**Frontend.ts:**

```
  onMount(async () => {
    // ask server for information based on a variable: example
    const example = "test";
    const example_reply = await pb.route(POST, '/api/myRoute', /*here, I would have to specify the fact that example is a form value of the POST request*/ example);
    // use example_reply
    if (example_reply === "cool_value") {
       console.log('got what I expected');
    } else {
       console.log('wrong!!!');
    }
  }
```

Does the function I am looking for exist, or should I use raw JS to fetch information from my custom routes ?

I have tried to use raw javascript to send a post request, which works but does not use the pocketbase package. :

```
const response = await fetch('/api/example', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ example: "test" }), // Convert the input to JSON
      });
```

Comment: Hello.  I'm confused as to why this is marked as Svelte.  From what I read, pocketbase is just a REST API.  Any REST client should do.  Svelte is not a REST framework.

Comment: Good point, I removed the svelte tag

Comment: _"feels suboptimal"_... what makes you think that? All the [official examples](https://svelte.dev/repl/cb31be94ea444b41a11d1320d16ba6dc?version=3.32.3) look the same

Comment: True, I meant there should be a way to do that with pocketbase's package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the routing documentation at the very end they have this:

```
import PocketBase from 'pocketbase';

const pb = new PocketBase('http://127.0.0.1:8090');

await pb.send("/hello", {
    // for all possible options check
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#options
    query: { "abc": 123 },
});
```

[PocketBase Routing Documentation...](https://pocketbase.io/docs/js-routing/)

You can find the `hello` sample on the page or access the one you created. They expose the custom routes via the SDK using the `send()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The way to send request to custom pocketbase routes using javascript is the one mentioned in the question, with some adjustments :

```
  const formData = new URLSearchParams();
  formData.append('custom_param', 'custom_param_value');

  const response = await fetch(pb.baseUrl + '/api/customRoute', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: formData.toString(),
  });
  if (!response.ok)
  {
    throw new Error('');
  }
  const data: string = await response.text();
```

Indeed, Pocketbase custom routes are **not meant** to be accessed through the client-side sdk, but rather to allow other components of your project to access server-side information and logic **WITHOUT** going using the sdk.